# Chef: No such cookbook

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to provion my vm using vagrant and chef:

```
==> default: ====================================
==> default: Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
==> default: ====================================
==> default:
==> default: Missing Cookbooks:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: No such cookbook: windows
==> default:
==> default: Expanded Run List:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: * java
==> default:
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
==> default:
```

My vagrant structure is:

```
VagrantFile
├───chef
│   ├───cookbooks
│   │   ├───apt
│   │   ├───java
│   ├───roles
│   │   ├───java-dev-workstation.rb
```

`Vagrantfile` content is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.roles_path = "chef/roles"
    chef.cookbooks_path = "chef/cookbooks"
    chef.add_role "java-dev-workstation"
  end
end
```

And `java-dev-workstation.rb`:

```
name "java-dev-workstation"

default_attributes( 
  # Because it's Oracle, we need to agree to the terms and conditions.
  :java => { 
    :install_flavor => 'oracle',
    :jdk_version => '8',
    :accept_license_agreement => true,
    :oracle => { "accept_oracle_download_terms" => true } 
  }

)

run_list(
  "recipe[java]"
)
```

I'm using Chef 12.18.31.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java` cookbook depends on the `windows` cookbook, which you don't have downloaded and so it cannot proceed. This is why people generally use Berkshelf or the Policyfile system as both of those download dependencies automatically for you.

And to answer your likely next question: yes you need the dependency even though you aren't using a Windows VM, we don't have any way to do optional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with previous comment. So not to add all the dependencies manually use vagrant-berkshelf plugin - https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf

All you need to do:

1. Declare all the dependencies ( in your case it is only java cookbook, berkshelf will take care silently about cookbooks java cookbook depends on - windows, so on .. ) in proper Berksfile
2. Point a Berksfile location in your Vagrantfile